# Resources for pylons development

Tags: python, mongodb, nginx, pylons

Are there any good resources for pylons development?

I want to build a pylons app and run it on nginx (for speed)

I am looking to use mongo for the db.

Given this stack are there any resources that would point me in the right direction? 
Any tips / suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and they are free:
the pylons book: http://pylonsbook.com/

And the Pylonshq, where you can find more updated info, for example im not using the authkit that the book use, its kinda unsuported, I use the repoze.what and repoze pluggins for authentication and authorization
http://wiki.pylonshq.com/dashboard.action

About the pylons mongodb integration (bad news by the way, it's kinda triky):
http://niallohiggins.com/2010/06/20/python-mongodb-and-pylons-connection-handles-and-all-that-lark/

Comment: Regarding the pylons book, beware that some of it is misguided/convoluted (chapter 14 gave me a lot of headaches). When it starts to feel laborious, skip around. Otherwise it's a great way to get started and it covers a generous amount of material.

I also second using repoze.who/what. Authkit felt half baked, repoze makes a lot of sense.